# Add node and elements in xml using C#/Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I  have an xml file like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>  
  <FeaturedProductCategories>
    <FeaturedProductCategory>
      <FeaturedProducts>
        <FeaturedProduct>
          <ContentSelector datavalue_idtype="content:smartform" datavalue_displayvalue="«Smart Form:49»">49</ContentSelector>
        </FeaturedProduct>
      </FeaturedProducts>
    </FeaturedProductCategory>
  </FeaturedProductCategories>
</root>
```

I want to modify it like the one below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <Title>HomePage</Title>
  <FeaturedProductCategories>
    <FeaturedProductCategory>
      <FeaturedProducts>
        <FeaturedProduct>
          <Products>
            <Product>
              <ProductTitle>Product</ProductTitle>
              <ProductDate>03-08-2012 11:57:25</ProductDate>
              <ProductImage>
                <img src="ex1.jpg" />
              </ProductImage>
              <ProductThumbnailImage>
                <img src="ex2.jpg" />
              </ProductThumbnailImage>
              <ProductCaption>Product Caption</ProductCaption>
              <ProductImage>
                <img src="ex3.jpg" />
              </ProductImage>
              <ProductThumbnailImage>
                <img src="ex4.jpg" />
              </ProductThumbnailImage>
              <ProductCaption>Product Caption</ProductCaption>
            </Product>
          </Products>
        </FeaturedProduct>
      </FeaturedProducts>
    </FeaturedProductCategory>
  </FeaturedProductCategories>
</root>
```

All the new nodes and values are to be added through a C# function. Let us assume these new values as static values for now.

Also the node "FeaturedProduct" is not only one. There are a lot of nodes in that name. I want to modify all the "FeaturedProduct" nodes.

Comment: Cool. So what's your question?

Comment: @Coeffect: I want to modify the xml as shown. Could you please suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't use linq exactly, but It will serve your purpose

```
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.Load("filename.xml");

        foreach (XmlNode xNode in xDoc.SelectNodes("//FeaturedProduct"))
        {
            XmlElement newElement = xDoc.CreateElement("newElementName");
            XmlAttribute newAttribute = xDoc.CreateAttribute("AttributeName");
            newAttribute.Value = "attributeValue";
            newElement.Attributes.Append(newAttribute);

            xNode.AppendChild(newElement);
            xNode.InnerText = "myInnerText";
        }
```

Also, [This Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) is a very handy reference for Xpath

Comment: Can I delete the node "<ContentSelector>" by searching with its name?

Comment: After making use of intellesence, I came up with the following: `xNode.RemoveChild(xNode.SelectSingleNode("ContentSelector"));`

Comment: @DotNetBeginner  I've edited my answer, adding               `xNode.InnerText = "myInnerText";`

Comment: Now I am able to add nodes under <FeaturedProduct> using your code. But, how can I add nodes to the nodes added under <FeaturedProduct>. For example from your code, I want to add a node under <newElementName> in the same foreach loop. Is that possible?

Comment: @DotNetBeginner yes it is possible, you can do it in the exact same way as you added a node to `<FeaturedProduct>`  just create another new element and call `newElement.AppendChild(newerElemeent)`

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the `XDocument` class here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

I had to do something very similar to this a couple of weeks ago; XDocument is more willing to manipulate data, and using LINQ with it is incredibly easy.

Comment: Do I need to write
doc.Root.Element("FeaturedProductCategories").Element("FeaturedProductCategory").Element("FeaturedProducts").Element("FeaturedProduct").Add(new XElement("Products"));
for creating a node under "FeaturedProduct"? It will be great if there is an easy way to search the node "FeaturedProduct" and add a child to it.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can try:
`XmlNode appNode = xml.SelectSingleNode("//FeaturedProductCategories/FeaturedProductCategory/FeaturedProducts/FeaturedProduct")
XmlElement appTag = xml.CreateElement("Products");
XmlElement newApp = xml.CreateElement("Product");
newApp.SetAttribute("name", "value");
appNode.AppendChild(appTag);
appTag.AppendChild(newApp);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with Linq:

```
        string documentXml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
<root>
    <FeaturedProductCategories>
        <FeaturedProductCategory>
            <FeaturedProducts>
                <FeaturedProduct>
                    <ContentSelector datavalue_idtype=""content:smartform"" datavalue_displayvalue=""«Smart Form:49»"">49</ContentSelector>
                </FeaturedProduct>
            </FeaturedProducts>
        </FeaturedProductCategory>
    </FeaturedProductCategories>
</root>";

        string productsXml = @"<Products>
    <Product>
        <ProductTitle>Product</ProductTitle>
        <ProductDate>03-08-2012 11:57:25</ProductDate>
        <ProductImage>
            <img src=""ex1.jpg"" />
        </ProductImage>
        <ProductThumbnailImage>
            <img src=""ex2.jpg"" />
        </ProductThumbnailImage>
        <ProductCaption>Product Caption</ProductCaption>
        <ProductImage>
            <img src=""ex3.jpg"" />
        </ProductImage>
        <ProductThumbnailImage>
            <img src=""ex4.jpg"" />
        </ProductThumbnailImage>
        <ProductCaption>Product Caption</ProductCaption>
    </Product>
</Products>";

        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(documentXml);

        var targetNodes = from featuredProduct in document.Descendants("FeaturedProduct")
                          from contentSelector in featuredProduct.Elements("ContentSelector")
                          select contentSelector;

        foreach (var targetNode in targetNodes)
        {
            targetNode.ReplaceWith(XElement.Parse(productsXml));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(document.ToString());
```