# Add Elements And Node in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have an application that is receiving the following XML, and I have to add some extra information (new elements). Could you please help me understand how to do it?

```
<Feed>
  <Claims>
    <Claim>
      <ClaimID>123</ClaimID>
      <Reference>245</Reference>
      <AccidentDetails>
        <IncidentDate>2015-08-05</IncidentDate>
      </AccidentDetails>
      <DriverDetails>
        <DriverFirstName>Text</DriverFirstName>
        <DriverLastName>Text</DriverLastName>
      </DriverDetails>
      <ClientVehicleDetails>
        <VehicleLegallyDriveable>Yes</VehicleLegallyDriveable>
        <VehicleLocation>In Use</VehicleLocation>
      </ClientVehicleDetails>
    </Claim>
  </Claims>
</Feed>
```

But I need to load the XML and add a section like below

```
<Feed>
  //This is the section I need to add to my XML
  <Control>
    <Username>Test</Username>
    <Password>TestPass</Password>
  </Control>
  //The following XML will remain the same
  <Claims>
    <Claim>
      <ClaimID>123</ClaimID>
      <Reference>245</Reference>
      <AccidentDetails>
        <IncidentDate>2015-08-05</IncidentDate>
      </AccidentDetails>
      <DriverDetails>
        <DriverFirstName>Text</DriverFirstName>
        <DriverLastName>Text</DriverLastName>
      </DriverDetails>
      <ClientVehicleDetails>
        <VehicleLegallyDriveable>Yes</VehicleLegallyDriveable>
        <VehicleLocation>In Use</VehicleLocation>
      </ClientVehicleDetails>
    </Claim>
  </Claims>
</Feed>
```

Comment: The formatting here is too messy to tell what you are actually trying to add. The two sections don't have the same root nodes or overall structure, so please fix this up so that we can tell how to help you

Comment: Well, have you tried *anything* yet? This should be pretty simple in LINQ to XML - about 5 lines of code, to be honest. (Load the original doc, create a new doc, add the extra bits, then add the root element of the original doc to it as an element under the root of the new doc.)

Comment: I Have the Model Class 

public class Claim {

  //claim
  public string ClaimID { get; set; }

  public string Reference { get; set; } ..... and Another one 
public class Control {

  public string Username { get; set; }

  public string Password { get; set; }

  public List<Claim> Claims { get; set; }

  
 }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add node and elements in xml using C#/Linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867659/add-node-and-elements-in-xml-using-c-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it with `LINQ-to-XML` like this:-

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("ClaimXMLFile");
XDocument xdoc2 = new XDocument(new XElement("Feed",
                                  new XElement("Control",
                                      new XElement("Username", "TestPass"),
                                      new XElement("Password", "Test")),
                                            xdoc.Root));
xdoc2.Save(@"NewXMLFileName");
```

Comment: Thank you #Rahul for your help @ you are Legend

Comment: You don't need to create a new document.  Using the Add method to the original element will achieve same results.